How do I find the point whereby the sequence similarity decreases or stops
I have two phased sequences that I am comparing to the T2T human assembly. I aligned the two phased sequences using the T2T as the reference. I want to find the point whereby the sequence similary decreases or 'falls off'. The hope is to find the breakpoint of sequence. I'm not sure of the appropriate tools to use and the approach to take. Creating a plot to visualise this would be helpful.
I have them aligned and did a dot plot to see could I notice anything. But I am unsure.
